# Display and analyze the graph of a website to check its connectivity and compute properties

Tags: website, data-visualization

I would like to check several properties of the graph behind a website I own. The properties I'm interested in are: diameter, shortest path from index page, min/max/average degree of vertices, and other properties that do not require solving a NP-complete problem. I'm also interested in tags that are not links, in order to check the programming style.

This is a Wordpress site, but I would like something generic. I've tried [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/), but the UI is not very good and I didn't find plugins to import or generate that kind of data. It should run under Linux or Mac OS X; I'm not looking for an online application.

Comment: In what format is the data available?  Do you have to interpret the graph, or do you have access to its raw data?  Can you post a sample?

Comment: The graph must be build from the HTML pages. What do you mean by interpret the graph ? Basically I want to iterate through the links of the first page of a website, add one vertex for each page and one edge for each link, until no new pages found, and repeat for each vertex. Then on this graph, I will compute the properties I mentionned above. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question intially, so my follow-up didn't make any sense.  It sounds like this is beyond what I could help with.  Good luck.

Comment: I have found a sample program that does a part of the job: Qt4 example 'Dom Traversal'. With a bit of work I should be able to implement what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try [NodeXL](http://nodexl.codeplex.com/) with the [VOSON Web crawl Spigot](http://voson.anu.edu.au/node/13#VOSON-NodeXL) (free account required).